# how to check if an sql query has returned null in jsp using jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

how to know if there is a row or not for the following specified query

```
<sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
  SELECT * from users where user='abcd';
</sql:query>
```

I know how to do it in servlet

```
          status=false;
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          String sql;
          sql = "SELECT * FROM users where uname='"+uname+"';";
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
          status=rs.next();
```

how to do the same thing using jstl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${result.rowCount == 0}">
            /* No results */
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            /* do what ever you want with the results */
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Also you can use

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
```